# Diffrent behavior of NULL asignment in C

Tags: c

I wrote below function to free a binary tree, but the address sanitizer reports heap-use-after-free at the marked line in the second recursion.

```c
void freeTree (tree_t * tree) {
    tree_t * p = tree;
    while (p->left != NULL) {   // <- heap-use-after-free
        freeTree (p->left);
    }
    while (p->right != NULL) {
        freeTree (p->right);
    }
    free (p);
    p = NULL;
}
```

However, after I moved the NULL assignment (as shown below), the issue disappeared.  Why is that?  Aren't they doing the same thing?

```c
void freeTree (tree_t * tree) {
    tree_t * p = tree;
    while (p->left != NULL) {
        freeTree (p->left);
        p->left = NULL;        // Added
    }
    while (p->right != NULL) {
        freeTree (p->right);
        p->right = NULL;       // Added
    }
    free (p);
    // p = NULL;               // Removed
}
```

---

### Edit

#### Definition of tree_t type

```c
typedef struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode * left;
    struct TreeNode * right;
} tree_t;
```

#### Initialization of a new tree node

```c
tree_t tree = malloc (sizeof *tree);
tree->val = 1;
tree->left = NULL;
tree->right = NULL;
```

Comment: Can you provide more details as to how you're allocating and using the binary tree?

Comment: Well, the `p = NULL;` you removed did absolutely nothing. It changed a local variable that's never used again. So that was obviously wrong.

Comment: `p = NULL` and `p->left = NULL` look pretty differently to me. It would be a bit of a miracle if they did the same thing, wouldn't it?

Comment: Also can you explain me like I'm five why you are using `while` in that function? What are you looping over?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI `while` is a mistake, thank you for point it out.  I didn't intended to use recursion at the beginning, but forgot the `while` afterwards.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger, it should become obvious. At some point you'll do that in your mind to find it, but the debugger still remains an invaluable tool every programmer should learn to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct problems you had in your first snippet:

- You had two infinite loops. You somehow expected `p->left` to change in the first loop, but nothing was assigned to it in the loop. Same with `p->right` in the second.
- `p = NULL;` didn't do anything. It changed a local variable that's never used again.

Your correctly fixed the second problem by removing the dead code.

You found a very convoluted way of fixing the first. The correct solution is to not use a loop at all.

```c
void freeTree( tree_t *node ) {
   if ( node->left )
      freeTree( node->left );

   if ( node->right )
      freeTree( node->right );

   free( node );
}
```

Or if you want to allow `NULL` to be provided:

```c
void freeTree( tree_t *node ) {
   if ( !node )
      return;

   freeTree( node->left );
   freeTree( node->right );

   free( node );
}
```

---

It seems to me you expected `p = NULL;` to somehow change some variable in the caller. Of course, that's not the case. If you wanted a variable in the caller, you'd need something like this:

```c
void freeTree( tree_t **node_pp ) {
    tree_t *node = *node_pp;

    if ( !node )
       return;

    freeTree( &node->left );
    freeTree( &node->right );

    free( node );

    // Set the variable the caller passed as an argument to NULL.
    *node_pp = NULL;
}
```

But that seems needlessly convoluted to me.